# Dockerfile and environnement variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a strange behavior with my Dockerfile. I try to make it write file with text coming from environment varibales :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV KEY ''
ENV VAL ''

RUN echo "${KEY}:${VAL}" > /etc/test

CMD []
```

I built this image and run it like this :

```
docker run -it --rm -e KEY=aaa -e VAL=bbb mytest
```

If I display the /etc/test file, it is empty (it is present, but empty). It seems that when it creates the file, environment variables are not set.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command in the docker file `RUN echo "${KEY}:${VAL}" > /etc/test` is executed when you **build** the image using `docker build ...`

Thus this is logical, since at that point the env variables are empty.
You need to move the commad to the CMD command which will run when the image is started.

Answer (score 0):

You can define KEY and VALUE as arguments and set their values when you're building the docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ARG KEY
ARG VAL

RUN echo "${KEY}:${VAL}" > /etc/test

CMD []
```

Then you can build the image using like this:

```
docker build --build-arg KEY=<value> --build-arg VAL=<value> .
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables

Comment: Hmmm ... this means that you need to build as many images as you have key value pairs. In my case why not ...

Comment: If you prefer to build a single image, and change your KEY and VAL values at run time, you can create a script and run it as an entrypoint and pass the values as environmental variables to the docker container.